# Proving $(p \oplus q) \oplus r=p \oplus (q \oplus r)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I was assigned to prove the associative law on xor.

$(p \oplus q) \oplus r=p \oplus (q \oplus r)$

I'm sure

$(p\oplus q)=(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)$

But I got stuck on

$(p \oplus q) \oplus r=[{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)}∧¬r]∨[¬{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)}]∧r$

What tatuologies (laws) would I need to prove the associative law for xor?

How do I relate those $p$ and $q$ to $r$ in order to prove it?

Any tips/advise would be appreciated.

Comment: What you've written is the associative law, not the distributive law. Do you mean the associative law?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already know that $\oplus$ is commutative. Thus $p \oplus (q \oplus r)$ is obtained from $(p \oplus q) \oplus r$ by exchanging the roles of $p$ and $r$. Therefore it will be enough to find an expression for $(p \oplus q) \oplus r$ that is symmetric in the variables $p$ and $r$.

Your steps to
$$(p \oplus q) \oplus r=[\{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)\}∧¬r]∨[¬\{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)\}]∧r$$
are correct.

Continue the calculation by applying the distributive law to $\{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)\}∧¬r$. Then apply De Morgan's Law to $¬\{(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)\}$. After that you will need to apply the distributive law repeatedly to obtain a disjunction on the right.

Comment: How can I distribute {(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q)}∧¬r ? I mean, in order to apply distributive law, I thought at least one of p or q should remain same.

Comment: You don't want to do that. The $\lnot$ takes precedence. Apply it first, using De Morgan's Law.

Comment: I guess this is where I got stuck. While distribute with ¬r for (p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧q), did you mean ¬ should be applied for both parenthesis first?

Comment: You have an expression of the form $(A \lor B) \land C$, where $A = p \land \lnot q$, $B = \lnot p \land q$, and $C = \lnot r$. To apply the distributive law, the first step will be to write $(A \land C) \lor (B \land C)$ with the appropriate values for $A$, $B$ and $C$. Then keep simplifying from there.

Comment: Oh, so should I also go over the right hand side in order to show that xor on associative law is tatuology?

Comment: Minjae, perhaps you could make an edit to your question showing how far you've gotten with these hints, and where you're stuck now. It will make it easier to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of XOR denoted as "J" in Polish notation, indicates the following two if-then rules hold:

1. If the left argument is false, then the value of Jpq is the right argument.  Or in short, if p = 0, then Jpq = q.
2. If the left argument is true, then the value of Jpq is the negation of the right argument.  Or equivalently, if p = 1, then Jpq = Nq.

Using these rules we have that

J J0b c = Jbc.  substituting p with 0 and q with b in the first rule above (p / 0, q / b hereafter) we have J0b = b.

J 0 Jbc = Jbc.  in the first rule p / 0, q / Jbc yields this equality exactly.

So, JJ0bc = J0Jbc.

J J1b c = JNbc.  in rule 2 p / 1, q / b yields J1b = Nb.

J 1 Jbc = NJbc.  in rule 2 p / 1, q / Jbc yields this equality exactly.

Now suppose that b = 0.  Then

J N0 c = J1c = Nc.

N J0c = Nc.

And lastly suppose that b = 1.

J N1 c = J0c = c.

N J1c = NNc = c.

Since a = 0 or a = 1, and the above shows that if a = 0 or a = 1, then JJabc = JaJbc, it follows that for XOR, JJpqr = JpJqr.

This proof also ends up proving JNpq = NJpq, or JN = NJ for short.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learned any proof methods yet, but I hope I will be able to understand your answer one day :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I would use Venn diagrams to give a visual proof, similar to [here](http://www.onlinemath4all.com/proof.html).

Comment: It pretty much help me out understanding the logics in venn diagrams. Thanks! - professor advised me it is a good way to think of, but in the exam, I will have to use Keith's style of proof.